# How to add product in WooCommerce without selecting any category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to add a product in woocommerce plug-in without selecting any category. After some research, I found that there was an option for this in old versions of WooCommerce in this [Blog Post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/find-products-with-no-category/). I am using Woocommerce version **3.4.3** and Wordpress version **4.9.2**

I am adding product through Products->Add New Products and when I click on publish without selecting any category it automatically sets **uncategorized** as the category name for this product. My Template displays products only if a product doesn't have a category and setting category to **uncategorized** causes no product to be displayed. Therefore I need to add a product in woocommerce without any category. I am using the **Adventure Tours** Template.

Comment: "uncategorized" is not a product category, it is a non product category. It only shows that the product doesn't belong to any product category.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I know that, but my template requires the product to be not of any category.

Comment: I repeat "uncategorized" is a non product category and It works the same way than wordpress categories for normal posts (blog). So you will need to find out something else to solve your problem.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec That is exactly what I am also saying, I don't require uncategorized, i am also looking for that something else.